# Android Google map v2 with library project

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I have Google map v2 setup in an Android library project. There are two apps built on top of the library project. For shorter writing, I'll use these connotations to reference the various projects. **Project A** - The Android library project, **Project B** - Built on top of the Android library project - **Project C** - Also built on top of the Android library project.

**Project B** share the same package name as **Project A**. **Project C** has a different package name. In **Project A** maps have been embedded in different parts of the application.

With **Project B** the maps load in all the areas of the application the map has been embedded without a problem, however, with **Project C** the map only loads in one part of the application, the other parts, either it's a grey grid or a black view.

Here are the relevant parts of the manifest file that setups Google maps v2 Android.

**Project B** manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.projectb.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.projectb.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.projectb.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:name="com.projectb.app.App"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_title"
        android:theme="@style/Theme" >
        <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="@string/google_map_api_key" />
   </application>


</manifest>
```

**Project C** manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.projectc.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <uses-permission  android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.projectc.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.projectc.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:name="com.projectc.app.App"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_title"
        android:theme="@style/Theme" >
        <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="@string/google_map_api_key" />
   </application>


</manifest>
```

I used the different package names to setup their respective map API keys.

Is this a bug with Google maps v2 Android or I'm doing something wrong with the map API key setup.

Comment: if you change the package name then need to get the API key to relevant to this package. Build API key is worked for a particular package

Comment: I did that already. As stated above. The map shows nicely in one part of the application but the other parts of the application where the maps are embedded, doesn't show.

Comment: Then it should be work